# Compute $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left \lceil \frac{1}{x} \right \rceil}\prod_{k=1}^{\left \lceil \frac{1}{x} \right \rceil}e^{kx}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The way I did it was using $u=\frac{1}{x}$.
Then I simplified it in terms of a sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\int_{1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e^{\frac{k}{u}}}{u^2}du=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left ( \frac{e^k-1}{k} \right )$$
The whole thing becomes $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{e}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}})^n}{n!}$$
However, the answer says $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$.
What's the right way to speed integrate this?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine but you seem to have made some mistakes in your working. For instance, when you introduce the summation, the bounds of integration should become $n$ and $n+1$ rather than staying the same. Also, I'm not sure how you've integrated the product, as you should get

$$\frac{1}{u^2}\prod_{k=1}^n{e^{\frac{k}{u}}}\ =\ \frac{1}{u^2}\cdot e^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2u}}$$

which integrates to

$$-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\cdot e^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2u}}$$

Just remember that products and integrals can't be interchanged the same way summations can. And I think this is just a typo but $\lceil\frac{1}{x}\rceil$ is written twice in the question however $n+1$ is only written in the exponential and not also the product.

Comment: I don't see why the bounds should be $n$ and $n+1$ unless you change $\lceil{x\rceil}$ into $\lfloor{x+1\rfloor}$. If you partition the interval $[0,\infty)$ into intervals of length 1, which are $(1,2]$, $(2,3]$, $\ldots$, $(n-1,n]$ where $n \to \infty$, and integrate over each interval, then the ceiling of $u$ (if you consider Metallic Silver's u-sub) becomes the upper bound of the interval you are integrating over, which would be $n$ and not $n+1$.

Comment: The bounds should be $n$ and $n+1$ because summing from $n=1$ to infinity covers the full interval $[1, \infty)$. In this case, the ceiling of $u$ would be the same as $n+1$. If the bounds were $n-1$ and $n$, then summing from $n=1$ would correspond to the integral starting at $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: We are not starting at $n=1$. When you write $\int_1^{\infty} f(u)du = \int_1^2 f(u)du + \int_2^3 f(u)du + \ldots$, the ceiling of $u$ in the integral $\int_1^2 f(u)du$ equals $2$ because $1 < u \leq 2$ and you use the ceiling definition. Because of that first integral, we would have to start at $n=2$.

Comment: I just mean that $\int_1^{\infty}{f(u)du} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int_n^{n+1}{f(u)du}}$. Here, when $u\in (n, n+1]$ the ceiling of $u$ is equal to $n+1$. You could reindex the sum though to start at $n=2$ in which case, the interval becomes $(n-1, n]$ and the ceiling becomes $n$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for the input. 